# Which module to use for tracking pages browsed by users?

Tags: 7, charts

My requirement are:

- most viewed pages
- most 404
- most 403
- most referring pages
- most visitors

In addition provides charts and HTML table view for those data.

Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best tracking out there is [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and its not a module. You simply add the javascript provided by google to every page in your site and access all the info and much much more on google's analytic dashboard.

To add the javascript provided by google to your site other check the drupal module [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) or add it yourself through a template file or [drupal's add js function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Comment: I agree, but client wants Drupal side statistics too

Comment: I would suggest going with Google Analytics, and then using the [Google Analytics Reports](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module to bring some of the required reports into Drupal.

Comment: What do you mean drupal side statistics? It doesn't matter who collects the data. If your problem is that you have to present that information inside your site then you could start seeking on how to export the info from google analytics and importing it into your site.

Comment: What about most active users? If core statistics help me with it?

Comment: Most active users in what? In creating nodes? comments? logged in time? I believe that if you enable the statistics module then you easily get access to this kind of information with Views. e.g. creating a view that aggregates the numbers of comments posted by user.

Comment: Actually, there is a lovely module for integrating GA tracking into Drupal: http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics  It provides a lot more than is possible than with just manually adding the tracking code to a theme.

Comment: @Perisdr "Most active uses" I meant most visitors, sorry for  
misstatement. I would to use GA, but I did not get approval (quite big project, a lot of heads above)

Comment: I don't know any module about that. Maybe the statistics module has this info and you can expose it with views. With a fast search I have found some custom code that is propably outdated but will give you hints in the right direction. http://drupal.org/node/66638 and http://drupal.org/node/302030

Answer (score 2):

I use [statcounter](http://drupal.org/project/statcounter) and it tells me exact path of users.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the core Drupal statistics module and use views for configuring more detailed reporting

Your best option however, will be to use an analytics tool if you want to have charts and such like. You can try using google analytics, piwik analytics or open web analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option might be to consider the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module, of which [I recently became the new maintainer](https://www.drupal.org/node/2431251).

Comment: The "stable" 8.x-2.0 version of visitors was released in `2014-Jun-07` (O_o)

Comment: @NoSssweat : that's correct ... have you also seen the creation date of the issue I mentioned? Anyway: anybody (like you?) interested in something like becoming a co-maintainer (eg for the D8 branch): contact me ... please! Ps: "this" question was tagged with D7 ...

Comment: IMO you should remove/unpublish that "stable"/broken version, it gives people false hope.

Comment: Hey @NoSssweat: would you mind QA-reviewing the updated project page for the visitors? Any additional (constructive) feedback welcome, as always!

Comment: Maybe you should add that blue box that says something like "This module is currently being ported to Drupal 8, but is not usable yet. Help us by following this issue." I think there is a "needs to be ported" version of the blue box.

Comment: @NoSssweat : ggggggrrrrrrrrrrrr ... **BUT**: you're right. Please go check again, to verify if you can think of any other refinements. Also check the various issue-links ... and make sure to read the last paragraph of [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2599042#comment-11372251) ... PS: are you aware that adding such "blue box" on a project page violates a D.O permission, which is that only project (co-)maintainers can update anything on project pages (pick a random project, create such special blue-box related issue, and go check the project page again). IMO that's not right ...